# Order status change email - WooCommerce V 2.6.9

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Could someone let me know if out the box WooCommerce V 2.6.9 will automatically send an email to the customer when the order status is changed in the backend by admin managing the order?

At first I thought we could be suffering from emails not being delivered, but now I'm using pepipost and I'm not actually seeing the emails triggered after an order status update - For example changing the status to 'Ready for collection'

DO I have to add this ?

Thanks for any support!

Comment: Not sure I follow?

Comment: Sorry I have miss to put the link (this was the track to start): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716196/send-an-email-notification-when-custom-order-status-changes-in-woocommerce/43717955#43717955