# Add custom order status and send email on status change in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

I want to add custom order status in my woocommerce site.And whenever status changes to that custom status I want to send mail.
I have tried ***[Send an email notification when custom order status changes in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716196/send-an-email-notification-when-custom-order-status-changes-in-woocommerce)***
as well as ***https://github.com/sarun007/custom-email-plugin/tree/master***
But didn't worked
I am using woocommerce **3.2.6** version

Answer (score 3):

**New version code**: [Add a new order status that Send an email notification in WooCommerce 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64607271/add-a-new-order-status-that-send-an-email-notification-in-woocommerce-4/64608630#64608630)

---

To make it work for a new custom order status (here "Awaiting delivery") you should need:

- to register the custom new order status first,
- to display it in bulk edit dropdown on admin orders list *(optional)*,
- to display it in order edit pages status dropdown
- to send an customized email notification when an order get this custom status.

The code:

```
// register a custom post status 'awaiting-delivery' for Orders
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_post_status', 20 );
function register_custom_post_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-awaiting-delivery', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Awaiting delivery', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Awaiting delivery <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Awaiting delivery <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
}

// Adding custom status 'awaiting-delivery' to order edit pages dropdown
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'custom_wc_order_statuses', 20, 1 );
function custom_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-awaiting-delivery'] = _x( 'Awaiting delivery', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    return $order_statuses;
}

// Adding custom status 'awaiting-delivery' to admin order list bulk dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 20, 1 );
function custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    $actions['mark_awaiting-delivery'] = __( 'Mark Awaiting delivery', 'woocommerce' );
    return $actions;
}

// Adding action for 'awaiting-delivery'
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'custom_email_actions', 20, 1 );
function custom_email_actions( $action ) {
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-awaiting-delivery';
    return $actions;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-awaiting-delivery', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 1 );

// Sending an email notification when order get 'awaiting-delivery' status
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_awaiting-delivery', 'backorder_status_custom_notification', 20, 2);
function backorder_status_custom_notification( $order_id, $order ) {
    // HERE below your settings
    $heading   = __('Your Awaiting delivery order','woocommerce');
    $subject   = '[{site_title}] Awaiting delivery order ({order_number}) - {order_date}';

    // Getting all WC_emails objects
    $mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

    // Customizing Heading and subject In the WC_email processing Order object
    $mailer['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->heading = $heading;
    $mailer['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->subject = $subject;

    // Sending the customized email
    $mailer['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works *(should work on any Woocommerce versions above 2.5)*

> In others function if you use the WC_Order method `update_status()` to change an order to 'awaiting-delivery' status like:
>
> ```
> $order->update_status();
> ```
>
> the **related email notification will be sent** too.

Comment: Thanks Loic,I will try this one

Comment: i have tried,but its not working.it adds status in drop down but it does not set that in  email settings

Comment: @ShrutiKharge The answer here is just answering your initial question. To add a new email notification in backend for a custom order status, is just another question that has nothing to do with what you asked here.

Comment: this works great and is working perfectly fine. However, I was wondering if it's possible to change the body text of the email as well? Just like the snippet is using $heading and $subject is it then possible to use $message_body or something similar?

Comment: @TobiasM I don't think so… In this case you should need something different and more complicated with a custom email notification.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec your code works great, but when I implemented it in my codes, the hooked action to `woocommerce_order_status_(to)` to trigger the email not working! why you remove `wc-` from `add_action('woocommerce_order_status_awaiting-delivery', 'backorder_status_custom_notification', 20, 2);`? and what's the job of `send_transactional_email` add action? thanks.