# split order and notify admin woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, product

I have the following code to split an order and create a new order with a custom status.

What I require is to notify the administrator when that new order is generated. So far the notification codes for a custom order have not worked.

The code to divide it that I am using is this:

function action_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ) {
// Initialize
$check_for_back_orders = false;

```
// Loop through order items
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
    // Get product
    $product = $item->get_product();

    // Product is on backorder
    if ( $product->is_on_backorder() ) {
        // Will only be executed once if the order contains back orders
        if ( $check_for_back_orders == false ) {
            $check_for_back_orders = true;

            // Create new order with backorders
            $backorder_order = wc_create_order();
        }

        // Add product to 'backorder' order
        $backorder_order->add_product( $product, $item['quantity'] );

        // Delete item from original order
        $order->remove_item( $item->get_id() );
    }
}

// If current order contains backorders, retrieve the necessary data from the existing order and apply it in the new order
if ( $check_for_back_orders ) {
    // Recalculate and save original order
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->save();
    
    // Obtain necessary information
    // Get address
    $address = array(
        'first_name' => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
        'last_name'  => $order->get_billing_last_name(),
        'email'      => $order->get_billing_email(),
        'phone'      => $order->get_billing_phone(),
        'address_1'  => $order->get_billing_address_1(),
        'address_2'  => $order->get_billing_address_2(),
        'city'       => $order->get_billing_city(),
        'state'      => $order->get_billing_state(),
        'postcode'   => $order->get_billing_postcode(),
        'country'    => $order->get_billing_country()
    );

    // Get shipping
    $shipping = array(
        'first_name' => $order->get_shipping_first_name(),
        'last_name'  => $order->get_shipping_last_name(),
        'address_1'  => $order->get_shipping_address_1(),
        'address_2'  => $order->get_shipping_address_2(),
        'city'       => $order->get_shipping_city(),
        'state'      => $order->get_shipping_state(),
        'postcode'   => $order->get_shipping_postcode(),
        'country'    => $order->get_shipping_country()
    );
    
    // Get order currency
    $currency = $order->get_currency();

    // Get order payment method
    $payment_gateway = $order->get_payment_method();
    
    // Required information has been obtained, assign it to the 'backorder' order
    // Set address
    $backorder_order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $backorder_order->set_address( $shipping, 'shipping' );

    // Set the correct currency and payment gateway
    $backorder_order->set_currency( $currency );
    $backorder_order->set_payment_method( $payment_gateway );

    // Calculate totals
    $backorder_order->calculate_totals();

    // Set order note with original ID
    $backorder_order->add_order_note( 'Pedido a confirmar stock automatizado. Creado a partir del ID de pedido original: ' . $order_id );

    // Optional: give the new 'backorder' order the correct status
  $backorder_order->update_status( 'wc-shipping-progress' );
   // $backorder_order->update_status( 'on-hold' );

}
```

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 10, 3 );

```
The code for the new custom status is this:

// Register New Order Statuses
function wpex_wc_register_post_statuses() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-shipping-progress', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Confirmar Stock', 'WooCommerce Order status', 'text_domain' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Approved (%s)', 'Approved (%s)', 'text_domain' )
    ) );
}
add_filter( 'init', 'wpex_wc_register_post_statuses' );

// Add New Order Statuses to WooCommerce
function wpex_wc_add_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-shipping-progress'] = _x( 'Confirmar Stock', 'WooCommerce Order status', 'text_domain' );
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wpex_wc_add_order_statuses' );





 So far the notification codes for a custom order have not worked.
```

Comment: For the **split orders** feature, I will suggest using any paid or free plugin that is available, because there will be a lot more to handle during the split orders feature.

Comment: WC doesnt know what to do with your custom order status. You have to tell Woo when switch from status to status what to do.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716196/send-an-email-notification-when-custom-order-status-changes-in-woocommerce